# Why Can't generics Actions written in code need explicit parameter declaration

Tags: c#, generics

For some reason I have a feeling only Jon Skeet would know the answer to this but it's worth a shot.

I have this method stub which is used as a proxy to generate commands.

```
public static void SetCommand<T>(string commandName, Action<T> execution)
     where T : new()
{
    //Omitted unimportant
}
```

I have a function which is calling this code, but the behavior differs depending on how it's called.

If I call the code by explictly declaring an Action all of the parameter can resolve fine

```
 Action<ClassDeclarationOptions> test = (t) => { };
 SetCommand(GENERATE_CLASS_COMMAND, test);
```

However if I declare a function to represent my action

```
public static void GenerateClass(ClassDeclarationOptions classOptions)
{

}
```

Then I need to explictly declare the parameter when passing it to the function like so:

```
SetCommand<ClassDeclarationOptions>(GENERATE_CLASS_COMMAND, Commands.GenerateClass);
```

Can someone explain why the compiler cannot resolve my Generic Parameter from Method Definition

Comment: Imagine there's an overload on `Commands.GenerateClass` that takes a different parameter type, there'd be no way for the compiler to figure out which one to use.

Comment: @DavidG Good point I didn't think of that.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: There may be other reasons of course, but this is the first one that comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah I mean logically they should still be able to resolve it, if there was only one, maybe they just didn't feel like it was worth the time to program it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say there's an overload on `Commands.GenerateClass` that takes a different parameter type, for example:

```
public static void GenerateClass(SomeOtherClass stuff)
{
}
```

Now there's no way for the compiler to figure out which `GenerateClass` method to use. However, as soon as you specify the type parameter the ambiguity goes away.

So even if you had a single method and the compiler inferred the type arguments, you could add that second method later on and break existing code without even realising it. Much safer just to force code to be explicit.

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept this after the time limit dissapears!